# submit html select as multidimensional array like checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I am trying to submit a select fields input value in the same way as some checkboxes.

The checkboxes use an indexed array with the group id as the index with the value to submit to the php server eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[33]">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[34]">
```

What I would like to do is use the same format but using both the checkboxes and a select field to send the values for the same name eg.

```
<select id="select">
  <option name="group[35]" value="1">35</option>
  <option name="group[36]" value="1">36</option>
</select>
```

If I pick both of the first options it should return the following to php.

```
$_POST['group'] = [
  33 => 1,
  35 => 1,
];
```

Is there any native way to achieve this without using javascript to create new hidden fields based on the value of the select box when it changes eg.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#select')

const selected = select => 
  select[select.selectedIndex].value

const onChange = e => {
  const input = document.createElement('input')
  input.type = 'hidden'
  input.name = `group[${selected(e.target)}]`
  input.value = 1
  e.target.form.appendChild(input)
  console.log(`<input type="hidden" name="${input.name}" value="1" />`)
}

select.addEventListener('change', onChange, false)
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="select" name="group">
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use javascript then you can do that with php , once the form is submitted. Don't name your select box the same as group.

```
<form>
  <select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And then in PHP:

```
<?php     
$groups = $_POST['group'];
$groups[$_POST["select"]] = 1;

foreach($groups as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key => $val <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Unfortunately I don't have control of the php code being run, so had to go with the javascript solution. It's hacky, but it got the job done.